# Error when selecting an item in my spinner

Tags: android, spinner

I am getting an error java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.HashMap when i select a data on my spinner. I retrieve my data in my spinner from my database. Im am trying to have just only 1 class, when i select a item on my spinner it checks the id in my database to show filter and show only the selected id

Here is my spinner select

```
     ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list1 = new ArrayList<>();

      try
            {
                JSONArray JA = new JSONArray(result);
                JSONObject json;

                s_name = new String[JA.length()];
                s_gender = new String[JA.length()];

                for(int i = 0; i<JA.length(); i++)
                {
                    json        =  JA.getJSONObject(i);
                    s_gender[i] =  json.getString("s_gender");
                    s_name[i]   =  json.getString("s_name");
                }
                list1.add("All");
                for(int i = 0; i<s_name.length; i++)
                {
                    list1.add(s_name[i] + " "+s_gender[i]);
                }



            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            spinner_fn();


  ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> spinner =  new ArrayList<Object>(Games.this, layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, s_name);
        spinner1.setAdapter((SpinnerAdapter) spinner);
        spinner1.setSelection(0);
        spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = null;
                switch (position) {
                    case 1:
                        intent = new Intent(getApplication(), Basketball.class);
                        HashMap<Object, Object> map = (HashMap)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                        String news_id = map.get(Config.TAG_news_id).toString();
                        String title = map.get(Config.TAG_title).toString();
                        String content = map.get(Config.TAG_content).toString();
                        String n_date = map.get(Config.TAG_n_date).toString();
                        intent.putExtra(Config.News_id,news_id);
                        intent.putExtra(Config.Title,title);
                        intent.putExtra(Config.Content,content);
                        intent.putExtra(Config.N_date,n_date);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        break;
```

I am getting the error here saying in arraylist cannot be applied to java.lang.string

```
(Games.this, layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, s_name);
list1.add("All");
            for(int i = 0; i<s_name.length; i++)
            {
                list1.add(s_name[i] + " "+s_gender[i]);
            }
```

Comment: read the documentation. `getItemAtPosition(position)` does not return a HashMap, it returns a string. HashMap and String are completely different classes, you cannot cast a String as a HashMap. `(HashMap)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);` will not work.
Your `list1` is an arraylist of `HashMap`s, not `String`s. You cannot add a string to `list1` as an item, you need to add a `HashMap`

Answer (score 0):

//Remove this line 
`list1.add("All");`

use this.

```
          HashMap<String,String> stringHashMap=new HashMap<>();
            for(int i = 0; i<s_name.length; i++)
            {
               stringHashMap.put(s_name[i],s_gender[i]);
                list1.add(stringHashMap);
            }

 ArrayList<String> spinnerArray=new ArrayList<>();
        Map<String, String> map = stringHashMap;
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            spinnerArray.add(entry.getKey());
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> spinner = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Games.this, layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, spinnerArray);
        spinner1.setAdapter(spinner);
        spinner1.setSelection(0);
```

Comment: (Games.this, layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,  stringHashMap); having an error here sir says cannot resolve array constructor list

Comment: ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> spinner =  new ArrayList<Object>(Games.this, layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, list1);

Comment: I cannot start the activity sir, I am getting this java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.abe.ateneofiesta/com.example.abe.ateneofiesta.Games}: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.Map

Comment: @     Map<String, String> map = (Map<String, String>) list1;

Answer (score 0):

```
    list1.add(s_name[i] + " "+s_gender[i]);
```

here is an error, as list1 is ArrayList of HASHMAP (you have a lot of hashmaps in one arraylist), and you've tried to add usual String to this list. May be you wanted the next:

```
     for(int i = 0; i<s_name.length; i++)
        { 
           HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
           hashMap.put(s_name[i], s_gender[i]);
           list1.add(hashMap);
        }
```

Comment: (Games.this, layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, HashMap); having an error here sir says cannot resolve array constructor list